# Spring boot embedded tomcat ServerProperties bean not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, docker, spring-boot

I'm working on a spring boot application that I used **ServerProperties** to process properties read from my application.properties the problem is that the bean **ServerProperties**  is working well in my local machine but when I passed to the integration phase using docker tomcat ignore the values modified by this bean it's like that it's not existing

this my bean

```
    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}")
    private String embeddedTomcatKeyStorePassword ;

    @Value("${server.ssl.trust-store-password}")
    private String embeddedTomcatTrustStorePassword ;
    @Bean
         @Scope("singleton")
         public ServerProperties serverProperties() {
                final ServerProperties serverProperties = new ServerProperties();
                final Ssl ssl = new Ssl();

                log.info("server.ssl.key-store-password : ");
                final String keystorePassword   = Password.recoverPassword(embeddedTomcatKeyStorePassword);
                log.info("server.ssl.trust-store-password : ");
                final String trustStorePassword = Password.recoverPassword(embeddedTomcatTrustStorePassword);

                ssl.setKeyPassword(keystorePassword);
                ssl.setTrustStorePassword(trustStorePassword);

                serverProperties.setSsl(ssl);
                return serverProperties;
            }


server.ssl.key-store-password=f340b6a8c8b6ba0f1a5110b304cafeba14793c34b7fcc84d6c3dc8f2ddabdbf3
server.ssl.trust-store-password=3a572f3cd9010831a85150137b6481fbb815347e87cd634be08ef6c95599826d
```

Can someone explain to me why this solution work on local dev and not work when I deploy the app using docker thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check your local tomcat run configuration, probably, you use some VM options or other enviroment variables, like `-Dspring.profiles.active`, but not use them in docker run configuration.